# Sentinel-1 image backward

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, sar

I have this problem with my images of the Ross Ice Shelf:
[image]

This is an image that has been Radar - Radiometric- Calibrate- Amplitude_HH - Gamma0
followed by Speckle Filter.

This is what happens when I add a Geometric - Geolocation - Ellipsoid Correction - Geolocation Grid
[image]

This is what happens when I add Geometric - Geolocation - Ellipsoid Correction - Average Height Range Doppler

[image]

This is what the image looks like on Copernicus preview:
[image]

Any suggestions? I'm at a loss

Comment: what output coordinate system did you select?
Maybe it is worth comparing different image resampling methods. It looks like there is some NoData value imputed.

Comment: This is level-1 GRD EW, I selected Stereographic South Pole

Comment: please select Nearest Neighbor as interpolation method during the Ellipsoid Correction to see if it makes a difference.
Also try WGS84 as reference system for a test.

Comment: No luck on the Nearest Neighbor or WGS84

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: it does not happen in the previous version 6 of the SNAP software. I was using the latest version 7. Fixed by uninstalling new software and installing a the older version.